# Can't build android app in Jenkins

Tags: java, android, tomcat, jenkins, gradle

I have followed the directions here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-android-apps-with-jenkins in addtion to other items I've found on the web through searching, but still can't seem to get my Android app to build on Jenkins.

Here's the error I'm getting with debug turned on in my jenkins build:

```
com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException: Unable to get the Android SDK home directory.
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Make sure the environment variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME is set up.
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.findHomeFolder(AndroidLocation.java:220)
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getFolder(AndroidLocation.java:141)
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.defaultDebugKeystoreLocation(KeystoreHelper.java:84)
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.builder.signing.DefaultSigningConfig.initDebug(DefaultSigningConfig.java:59)
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.SigningConfig.<init>(SigningConfig.java:52)
23:37:55.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    ... 79 more
23:37:55.728 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
23:37:55.728 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
23:37:55.728 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
23:37:55.728 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
23:37:55.728 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 3.839 secs
```

Some pages indicated that the problem may be that `ANDROID_HOME` isn't set and the script says `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` can't be reached. I believed I had both of these set, so I added echos to my build step. Here's the result from the same output as above:

```
+ echo ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ANDROID_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
+ echo ANDROID_SDK_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
ANDROID_SDK_HOME /opt/android-sdk-linux
[Gradle] - Launching build.
```

And my android is installed in `/opt/android-sdk-linux`.

By going to `/opt/jenkins/workspace/[my project]` I ran gradle clean build. I found a permissions problem by doing this, so I ran `chmod -R +wx` to the whole workspace directory. My gradle build ran clean from the command prompt.

Went back to Jenkins and did build now on my project and it still failed exactly as above.

Jenkins is running in `/opt/tomcat` under tomcat. Tomcat is started with a damon script and that's how I'm setting the environment variables being used by Jenkins.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit on my build server.

Everyone has permission to `/opt/android-sdk-linux`

```
thomas@testbox:~$ ls -ld /opt/android-sdk-linux/
drwxrwxrwx 13 thomas thomas 4096 Sep 13 23:09 /opt/android-sdk-linux/
```

Ideas?

Comment: Has tomcat read permissions under `/opt/android-sdk-linux` ?

Comment: @larsgrefer Everyone does: thomas@testbox:~$ ls -ld /opt/android-sdk-linux/

drwxrwxrwx 13 thomas thomas 4096 Sep 13 23:09 /opt/android-sdk-linux/